# How to delete “empty code templates” in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

My professor took off points on an assignment for “leaving Empty Code Templates throughout my submission”. I’ve included a picture of what he was referring to. If anyone could help explain how to remove these?

[image: empty code template example]

I tried deleting them, hoping it would be all fine but I just get an error when I go back to my form.

Comment: Click on the associated controls in the designer view, and click the lightning bolt to view events. Delete them from there and you should be free to delete the leftover code.

Comment: The other way is to do it manually (so you can see what's going on). Right click on the method and choose "find all references". In all likelihood, there will be exactly one, a statement with a `+=` operator that establishes the event subscription (in the designer.cs file). Delete that one line. Then delete the method implementation (i.e., the event handler function) . Each time you do this, recompile (messing with the designer.cs file can foul things up). Or, just follow @Blue's suggestion

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [Blue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4875631/blue) in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75424285/how-to-delete-empty-code-templates-in-visual-studio-2019/75425219#comment133082686_75424285)

> Click on the associated controls in the designer view, and click the lightning bolt to view events. Delete them from there and you should be free to delete the leftover code.

It is a bad idea to edit event code signatures outside the designer.

Make sure you open the designer often or have frequent version control to avoid file corruption.

Comment: hi, thank you for your reply! I still need the controls in the design view, but I just don’t need the code coming up on the coding page.

Comment: @apollight Jio-gmail is right. Maybe you can delete the red line according to the error after simply deleting the statement. But you need to understand why the error occurs. When you double-click the event, the click event will be automatically generated to generate code and bind the event. You just need to click the lightning button, where you delete the associated event, and you can delete those codes at will. You should mark this answer as answer. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lm4hP.png